# Please suggest a graphics based PDF generator for Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I am currently using [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) in .NET to generate PDF documents which heavily use direct drawing methods to generate the output due to the format of these types of documents. This is an efficient format that creates vector based documents which are very small yet highly detailed.

I now have a need to do the exact same thing in Java. I have used iText in the past but found it restrictive and had to embed images which made the document very large and didn't scale well.

Comment: In iText too you can use direct drawing. You can use iText APIs or even awt API on the graphic device.

Comment: Just revisited iText in action 2nd edition and found the "Adding content at absolute positions" section. It's by far no way near as simple as a simple `graphics.fillRectangle(Brush, Rectangle)`; instead it requires 6 lines of code to achieve the same thing. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iText too you can use direct drawing. You can use iText APIs or even awt API on the graphic device.
Example of drawing a line:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
cb.saveState();
cb.setLineWidth(1.2);
cb.setColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.moveTo(x, y);
cb.lineTo(x + width, y);
cb.stroke();
cb.restoreState();
```